# Blender - Fisheye ( Panoramic camera not available in freestyle?)

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to render my project with Fisheye camera, but when I click render, I get an error message : Panoramic camera not available in freestyle? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not yet render a panoramic shot using the **freestyle** setting.

You must **uncheck** *freestyle*.

[image]

You can then try disabling *panoramic* view. (if you do not need it)

- select your camera
- switch from panoramic to perspective

[image]